multiline background imitating underline text
I've created a hover effect that works very nice with the one line text. Unfortunately it doesn't work when the text is multiline. I understand it's because it's adding the background to the paragraph, which contains the whole text but I have no idea how to modify it to fix it? Is it possible by changing the .underline class only? I'm using it as a separate class and I would like it to work for different elements in an existing website and whether the paragraph is single- or multiline depends on the screensize, so modifying the html is not really an anwser. Can you help?


div {
border-right: black 1px solid;
padding: 2px;
width: 150px;
}

.underline {
  cursor: pointer
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: linear-gradient(
                  to right,
                  green 0%, /* Green */
                  green 75%, /* Green */
                  red 75%, /* Red */
                  red /* Red */
  ) no-repeat 0 100%;
  background-size: 0 2px;
  transition: background-size 400ms;
}


.underline:hover {
    background-size: 100% 2px;
  }
<div class="container">
 <p class="underline">This text</p>
 <p class="underline">This another, multiline text</p>
 </div>




Strictly without editing the HTML, you can set display: inline:


div {
  border-right: black 1px solid;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 150px;
}

.underline {
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    green 0%, /* Green */
    green 75%, /* Green */
    red 75%, /* Red */
    red/* Red */
  ) no-repeat 0 100%;
  background-size: 0 2px;
  transition: background-size 400ms;
}

.underline:hover {
  background-size: 100% 2px;
}
<div class="container">
  <p class="underline">This text</p>
  <p class="underline">This another, multiline text</p>
</div>



Though this then means other layout side effects happen. To avoid this, you could adjust the HTML a little, though still without the knowledge of whether the text would be multiline or not:


div {
  border-right: black 1px solid;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 150px;
}

.underline {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    green 0%, /* Green */
    green 75%, /* Green */
    red 75%, /* Red */
    red/* Red */
  ) no-repeat 0 100%;
  background-size: 0 2px;
  transition: background-size 400ms;
}

.underline:hover {
  background-size: 100% 2px;
}
<div class="container">
  <p><span class="underline">This text</span></p>
  <p><span class="underline">This another, multiline text</span></p>
</div>



